# Random "production.ERROR: No application key has been specified." errors (In Local environment)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I randomly get the following error:

> "production.ERROR: No application key has been specified."

It doesn't bother much because it doesn't happen all the time and when it does the website just quickly refreshes, but I wonder where it comes from?

There is an application key and it happens randomly. Could that happen because I did not cache the config? Because I must not cache the config so I have to leave it un-cached

But also, why does it say `production.ERROR` if my `APP_ENV` is `APP_ENV=local`? (And when I type `php artisan env` it says that I'm really local)

Where should I look for to try to solve these 2 issues? (The wrong environment, and the random no app key errors?)

Comment: Don't you have to run `php artisan key:generate` to obtain new key? If you have APP_ENV=local set, do you have your configuration in `.env.local` file?

Comment: I have only `.env` file where `APP_ENV` is set to `local` but no `.env.local` as well. It does seem to read the other data correctly from the `.env`. In the `app.php` file, it says `'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production')`. Also, do I need to regenerate the app key?

Comment: Well, `.env.local` is not required because laravel will fall back to the `.env` file. Did you notice whether this error is logged when using some specific endpoint/view etc.?

Comment: Maybe, you're **setting** the environment to `production` instead of checking it somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Run the `php artisan key:generate` command to generate the application key

Comment: thank you, but there already is an application key and it happens randomly (not always). Could regenerating the key help?

Answer (score 0):

```
"Before using Laravel's encrypter, you must set a key option in your config/app.php in config file"
```

Please use `php artisan key:generate` command to generate key